# Can I buy a game in a bundle after getting a refund on the game?

Tags: steam

I just bought XCOM 2 on Steam sale, but after reviewing the bundles that contain it, I'd much rather have the whole XCOM 2 Collection and save money on the game and the DLCs. I can't buy the bundle now because the offer is only applicable when one doesn't already have an item from the bundle.

So I requested a refund on the purchase. Will it be possible to buy the bundle after refund? And in general, is is possible to buy a game a second time after getting a refund?

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out for you, but I'm confused by your claim that you can't buy the bundle after buying a single item from the bundle.  I've done this several times myself, and the bundle is correctly discounted to avoid double-charging me for the things I already own.  Am I missing something unique about your situation?

Comment: @Steve-O That's a relatively new feature that not all bundles use. It used to be you'd have to pay the same price for a bundle regardless what games or DLC in the bundle you already owned and a lot of bundles still work this way. The XCOM 2 Collection is an example of one of these older style of bundles. You can tell if it's a newer style bundle, with a reduced price if you already own part of it, by checking to see if it the word BUNDLE appears in light blue after it's name. Merely being called a bundle doesn't mean it's new style bundle, it's needs to be in all caps and in light blue.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks for the info!  I guess I've been pretty lucky with the bundles I've been choosing so far, but I'll definitely pay more attention to avoid being caught out by this in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is actually in the [Steam FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4873-QOSK-5126#sale):

> I bought a game right before it went on sale. Can I get a refund and repurchase it at the sale price?
>
> > Yes.
> >
> > If you have not already requested a refund, make sure the purchase is eligible and submit a request here.
> >
> > Please note that approved refunds may take up to 7 days to process.

And indeed it did work flawlessly, got the refund within an hour and could immediately order the bundle afterwards.